# How use different login for subdomains different with LoginManager flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the LoginManager to login to my site and I want to separate the user login from other logins. How would I separate login_view to different domains?

```
    login_manager = LoginManager(app)
    login_manager.login_view= 'authentication.login_trigo'
    db.init_app(app)


    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id)) 
    
    
    
    
    from .dashboards import dashboards
    
    from .authentication import authentication
    from .utility import utility    
    from .layouts import layouts
    from .auth_users import auth_users

    app.register_blueprint(dashboards ,url_prefix="/")    
    app.register_blueprint(authentication ,url_prefix="/")   
    app.register_blueprint(utility ,url_prefix="/")       
    app.register_blueprint(layouts ,url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(auth_users ,url_prefix="/")  

    return app
```